# How to show an success message in jquery dialog when it closed refreshing that page

Tags: php, jquery

Success and failure message are appearing in dialog above to form
What i need is showing success message in dialog box instead of form details and when user closes dialog refreshing test.php page how can i do this?

test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var currentOperation = "";
    $(function(){
        $('#Add').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            title : 'Add New'
        });
    });
    function openDialog(operation){
        currentOperation = operation; 
        $('#Add').dialog('open');
        $('#Add').html("Loading...");
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "addNewForm.php",                  
               data: "",
               success: function(msg){
                   $('#Add').html(msg);
               },
               error:function(msg){
                     $('#Add').dialog("close"); 
               }               
             });
    }
    function authenticate(){
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "addNew.php",                  
               data: $("#form").serialize(),
               success: function(msg){
                   if(msg=="success")
                   {
                       alert(msg);
                       $('#successful').html(msg);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $('#errorMessage').html(msg);
                   }
               },
               error:function(msg){
                    $('#Add').dialog("close"); 
               }               
             });
    }

    //-->
    </script>  

<div style='display: none;' id='Add'></div>
<p><a onclick=openDialog("AddNew") href="#" id="dialog_link"> Add New Details </a></p>
```

AddNewForm.php

```
    <div style="color:red" id="errorMessage"></div>
    <div  id="suceesful">
    <form action="addNew.php" method="POST" id="login_form"  onsubmit = "return false;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">user Name:</td>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                <input name="addDetails" type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick ="javascript:authenticate();" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
```

addNew.php

```
try{
require_once ('connect.php');
$username = $_POST ['userName'];
if ($username == NULL) {
        throw new Exception ( "A user name is required" );
}
$db->beginTransaction ();
$sql = $db->query(
            "INSERT INTO users (id,userName)
            VALUES( :p_id, :p_userName)", 
            array( 'p_id' => '', 'p_userName' => $userName)  
            );
$db->commit ();
if($sql)
{
    echo "Sucessfully Added";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

umm..im not sure if I undestood right but.. after success, write the message to session, and after page refresh check that value. if it's there, show it where ever you want and remove it from session.